# How to use request.vars in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I am trying to understand how request.vars works in web2py. I 'd appreciate some help.

```
def one():
    x = 5
    return dict(x=x)
```

If i want to get the value of variable x in an other function do I use request.vars? I tried this way but of course, it didn't work:

```
def two():
    y = request.vars.x
    return locals()
```

Comment: Assuming the functions `one` and `two` are actions in a controller, then they are completely independent (i.e., each would be called via separate HTTP requests) -- so you would not access the return value from one inside the other. It might help if you explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks very much! I would like to use the value of x in function two.(i.e., Let's say in function one, x = a + b, I can show this in view one {{=x}}. Then in function two I need to get the value of x and I want to add this value to c which will be a variable defined in function two, so this is what function two would look like: d = c + (the value of x from function one which is what I am trying to pass to function two) , then I wan to show this in view two {{=d}}

Comment: @Anthony I know I can just define a, b and x again in function two and then it will work but I thought that there might be a way to do this without having to define the same variables again in function two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.vars contains parameters passed in the body of an HTTP request (usually a GET or POST request derived from submitting a form).

In your example, once you've defined x you could redirect from one to two while passing x in a variable called `value`:

```
redirect(URL('two', vars=dict(value=x)))
```

Then in two you could access the value of x via `request.vars['value']`.

There is some additional detail in the documentation here: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#request

Comment: Although your answer worked, I still have an issue. I am able to pass the value of x to function two but if I try to a calulation using that value with an other variable in function two like this: z = request.vars['value'] y = 5,  and r = z + y, I get this error msg:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' Can you help me with this or I should post a new question for this?

Comment: z= int(request.vars ['value']) ?

Comment: @datasciThanks datasci, that works! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: While it is true that action `one` can redirect to `two` and pass a value in the query string, it is not clear why one would do this. If all action `one` does is redirect to action `two` (i.e., `one` never actually returns anything), then there is no point to having separate actions. You might as well make it a single action. If you instead need action `one` to return an HTML page and then have the action `two` page visited in a subsequent step, you should use the `session` or a link embedded in page `one`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27985101/440323).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the workflow you describe, it would probably make most sense to use the `session` to store the value of `x`.

In the controller:

```
def one():
    session.x = 5
    return dict()

def two():
    y = session.x
    return locals()
```

In the one.html view (as well as in the view of any other action, including `two`):

```
{{=session.x}}
```

Use the session to store values that need to be accessed by different controller actions during separate HTTP requests. `request.vars` simply captures the values passed in a URL query string or in the body of a POST request during a *single* HTTP request.

If the way users get to action `two` from action `one` is by clicking a link on the `one` page, another option would be to include the value of `x` in the query string of the link URL.

In the controller:

```
def one():
    x = 5
    return dict(x=x)
```

In the one.html view:

```
{{=x}}
<a href="{{=URL('two', vars=dict(x=x))}}">Go to two</a>
```

Then when the user clicks that link, in the `two` function, the value of `x` will be available in `request.vars.x` (though if the `two` page is visited by some other means, `request.vars.x` will be empty). Note, this method is less secure in the sense that someone can request the `two` URL and pass any arbitrary value of `x` in the query string. By using the session, you ensure that the value of `x` cannot be altered.

Comment: thanks very much.  You're right, using session is better in a sense that with session page `two` can be visited directly, otherwise it can only be visited from the link in page `one` and, as you said, the value of `x` can not be altered if I use session. Therefore, this is definitely the better way. Thanks very much for your help. I already marked the other answer as the best answer, it actually answers my initial question, but your answer takes it a step further and offers a better solution to my problem. So I am not sure  what to do, I should change the right answer mark?

Comment: hello Anthony I tried to change my code in my app to the session solution but there `x` is a float and for whatever reason it seems there is an issue: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: it seems the float is not the issue. In action `one` in my app `session.x = a + b` a and b are variables from action `one` both float. In action `two` I do this `float(session.x)` This works when I pass the vars but doesn't seem to work when I try the session, I get this error: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: Sounds like `session.x` might not yet have been defined, in which case, `session.x` will return `None`. Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: if `session.x` is defined as an int or a float it all works fine but if `session.x=` defined as a variable that is storing an int or a float, it doesn't work. For example: in action `one` h, g and t are variables storing int or float. `h` is defined like this `h=g+t` then I define `session.x` like this `session.x=h` then in action two I have this: `w=float(session.x) p=100 z=p-w` then in view.two I have this {{=z}} I get the following error:float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging. Check the actual value of session.x in the case where it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not so much *how* to do it but about understanding what request.vars *is* I'll add this:
(from: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching) - about 50 lines down...

> web2py maps GET/POST requests of the form:
>
> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/c/f.html/x/y/z?p=1&q=2`
>
> to function f in
>   controller "c.py" in application a, and it stores the URL parameters
>   in the request variable as follows:
>
> request.args = ['x', 'y', 'z'] and:
>
> **request.vars = {'p':1, 'q':2}** and:
>
> request.application = 'a' request.controller = 'c' request.function =
>   'f' In the above example,

So, to answer your question, the contents of `request.vars` is **simply the contents of the query parameters in the URL** that was used to call your controller function.

Comment: To be more precise, the variables in the query string of the URL are in `request.get_vars`. Variables submitted via a POST request are in `request.post_vars`. And `request.vars` stores both the `request.get_vars` and the `request.post_vars` (if the same variable name appears in both, then its values will be stored in a list in `request.vars`).

Comment: To be even more precise, if the input contains duplicated fields such as `http://localhost:8000/a/c/f?favorite_color=red&favorite_color=yellow`, the `request.get_vars['favorite_color']` will be a list already. Same applies to `post_vars` respectively.